# Fiori Element - On Save raise dialog

Tags: sapui5

We have created list report app using fiori elements. We now wanted to raise a dialog on 'Save' action, so we have used [ExtensionAPI for object page extensions](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.suite.ui.generic.template.ObjectPage.extensionAPI.ExtensionAPI)

```js
function onDialog(oEvent) {
       if (!That._oDialog) {
        sap.ui.core.Fragment.load({
         name: "MyProject.MyDialog",
         controller: this
        }).then(function (oDialog) {
         That._oDialog = oDialog;
         That.getView().addDependent(That._oDialog);
         That._oDialog.getBinding("items").filter(oFilters);
         That._oDialog.open();
        }.That(That));
       } else {
        That._oDialog.getBinding("items").filter(oFilters);
        That._oDialog.open();
       }
}

sap.ui.controller("NextGenerationMaintenanceUI.ext.controller.ObjectPageExt", {       

onAfterRendering: function () {
        debugger;
        this.extensionAPI.getTransactionController().attachAfterSave(onDialog);
       }
 });
```

Unfortunately, we are not able to access the view controller and getting the error "TypeError: (intermediate value).this is not a function"

Answer (score 0):

This should work, don't use that:

```
 then(function (oDialog) {
                this._oDialog = oDialog;
                this.getView().addDependent(That._oDialog);
            this._oDialog.getBinding("items").filter(oFilters);
                this._oDialog.open();
            }.bind(this))
```